# Karatsuba algorithm in ARM NEON implementation seems to have an error

Tags: arm, multiplication, neon, karatsuba

I found many copies of the same implementation of the Karatsuba algorithm for ARM NEON on the internet, including some science papers, eg   http://conradoplg.cryptoland.net/files/2010/12/mocrysen13.pdf

It looks like all these copies have the same glitch. While being said that it does arithmetic multiply, the result is still polynomial. If changing the `vmull.p8` to `vmull.u8` it produces a correct result for small numbers with one lowest word. But big numbers, that exceed lowest word, are not correct.
Implemention looks good:

```
.macro mul64_p8 rq rl rh ad bd k16 k32 k48 t0q t0l t0h t1q t1l t1h t2q t2l t2h t3q t3l t3h
    @A1
    vext.8  \t0l, \ad, \ad, $1
    @F = A1*B
    vmull.p8 \t0q, \t0l, \bd
    @B1
    vext.8  \rl, \bd, \bd, $1
    @E = A*B1 (7)
    vmull.p8 \rq, \ad, \rl
        @A2
        vext.8  \t1l, \ad, \ad, $2
        @H = A2*B
        vmull.p8 \t1q, \t1l, \bd
        @B2
        vext.8  \t3l, \bd, \bd, $2
        @G = A*B2
        vmull.p8 \t3q, \ad, \t3l
            @A3
            vext.8  \t2l, \ad, \ad, $3
            @J = A3*B
            vmull.p8 \t2q, \t2l, \bd
    @L = E + F
    veor    \t0q, \t0q, \rq
            @B3
            vext.8  \rl, \bd, \bd, $3
            @I = A*B3
            vmull.p8 \rq, \ad, \rl
        @M = G + H
        veor    \t1q, \t1q, \t3q
                @B4
                vext.8  \t3l, \bd, \bd, $4
                @K = A*B4
                vmull.p8 \t3q, \ad, \t3l
    @t0 = (L) (P0 + P1) << 8
    veor    \t0l, \t0l, \t0h
    vand    \t0h, \t0h, \k48
        @t1 = (M) (P2 + P3) << 16
        veor    \t1l, \t1l, \t1h
        vand    \t1h, \t1h, \k32
            @N = I + J
            veor    \t2q, \t2q, \rq
    veor    \t0l, \t0l, \t0h
        veor    \t1l, \t1l, \t1h
            @t2 = (N) (P4 + P5) << 24
            veor    \t2l, \t2l, \t2h
            vand    \t2h, \t2h, \k16
                @t3 = (K) (P6 + P7) << 32
                veor    \t3l, \t3l, \t3h
                vmov.i64 \t3h, $0
    vext.8  \t0q, \t0q, \t0q, $15
            veor    \t2l, \t2l, \t2h
        vext.8  \t1q, \t1q, \t1q, $14
                vmull.p8 \rq, \ad, \bd
            vext.8  \t2q, \t2q, \t2q, $13
                vext.8  \t3q, \t3q, \t3q, $12
    veor    \t0q, \t0q, \t1q
    veor    \t2q, \t2q, \t3q
    veor    \rq, \rq, \t0q
    veor    \rq, \rq, \t2q
.endm
```

But why is it not correct as stated? Basically I need an efficient 64x64=128 arithmetic operation for arm-v7a, and looks like NEON is the only choice here.

It feels like losing a carry flag somewhere among these operations, because results I observe are quite close to correct ones.

Comment: I have "no" idea what the code presented is *trying* do (probably successfully). It certainly doesn't look 64x64=128. Start with `VMULL.U32`, and just do "long multiplication": with operand small as this (double the factor length supported), carry handling alone will kill any advantage of needing less multiplies.

Comment: (Or even (in AArch64 mode) UMULH, else UMULL.) Is this *I want to use a fast `64x64=128`* or *I want to know/learn/practise how to implement a fast `64x64=128`*? For the former, a self-respecting compiler should be able to guide you.

Comment: (`carry handling alone will kill any advantage` or [does it](http://arith24.arithsymposium.org/slides/s2-liu.pdf)?)